# how to check if an item in combobox is already in the listbox?

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a seat booking form that asks the user for their full name(textbox) and seat of choice(combobox) before a button is pressed to confirm the booking. If name was not entered, a msgbox comes up asking them to input name. If the seat of choice is already in a listbox that shows all bookings so far, a msgbox comes up to choose another seat as it has already been reserved. The seat options in the combobox are named A1, A2 etc.

When I run the code the check for name is successful. However, even if the seat of choice is already in the listbox, the prompt to choose another seat does not show up. What am I doing wrong?

Dim buyers(0) As person

```
    buyers(0).firstname = firstnamebox.Text
    buyers(0).surname = lastnamebox.Text
    buyers(0).seatchoice = seatlist.SelectedItem


    If firstnamebox.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then                     
        MsgBox("please include a name")
    ElseIf lastnamebox.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then
        MsgBox("please include full name")
    ElseIf bookingdetails.Items.Contains(seatlist.SelectedItem) Then
        MsgBox("This seat is already taken please pick another")
    Else
        bookingdetails.Items.Add(buyers(0).getfullname & " , " & buyers(0).seatchoice)

    End If
```

I expect a msgbox to pop up saying "This seat is already taken please pick another" if the bookingdetails listbox already contains the selected item in the combobox. But it seems to just ignore it...

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct listbox?

Comment: yep there is only one listbox, (bookingdetails)

Comment: Separate the if statements

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there could be some spelling/case issues with your procedure. The `Contains` method is case sensitive, and you should at least be converting source and target strings `ToUpper` and perhaps trim for good measure. Ultimately, though, I think you are giving to much credit to the end user not to make a mistake.

here's an example

```
Dim LstBxItms() As String = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object).Select(Function(obj) ListBox1.GetItemText(obj).ToUpper.Trim).ToArray
If LstBxItms.Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToUpper.Trim) Then
    MsgBox("Found match")
End If
```